# compare time portion of date on grails query

Tags: mysql, date, grails

I dont now how to compare date and time portion in a grails query. I use Mysql and grails 2.3.8. My domain class has two Date type properties and  DATETIME Types in Mysql. Then I need to execute a sql query (criteria,createcriteria...etc) with the date or time part.

*f1 > initialdate , here i need only the date part (yyyy-MM-dd)*

and other query

f1 > inititaldate, here i need only the time part (HH:mm)

I am getting inconsistent results:

```
def resultado = Reservacion.where {

year(fhfinal) == reservacionInstance.fhinicio.toCalendar().get(Calendar.YEAR)

 &&
month(fhfinal) == reservacionInstance.fhinicio.toCalendar().get(Calendar.MOTH)

}.list()
```

Comment: What do you mean by *inconsistent results*?

Answer (score 0):

MYSQL:Time(0) in database

date_format(domainname_.propertiename,'%Y-%m-%d')

date_format(domainname_.propertiename,'%k:%i')

It is working but I'd like using HQL